# What is the SWT key constant for the menu key

Tags: java, key, swt, keycode

Does anyone know what the key constant in SWT is for the menu key on the keyboard (right next to right-Ctrl)?

This key has a virtual key code of 0x5D (93). I need it for correct key combination detection.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no constant defined for the <kbd>Menu</kbd> key.

In order to detect if a context menu was opened by mouse or by keyboard, you should add a `MenuDetectListener`. The `detail` field of its `MenuDetectEvent` is either `SWT.MENU_MOUSE` or `SWT.MENU_KEYBOARD`.

Comment: Actually I am using low level hook and process it with low level event, so it would not be convenient way to add higher level listener to this.

Comment: @Infinito The equivalent low level event is `SWT.MenuDetect`, the detail field is the same.